# Trump's pre-election claims. How many are in progress?

Tags: united-states, economy, donald-trump, geopolitics, globalization

Trump's pre-election company was bright. There were big pre-election claims:

- breaking disadvantageous deals
- wall on Mexican border
- removing 'Obamacare'
- moving embassy to Jerusalem
- new workplaces for US
- solving immigration problems

How much he has done? Modern news world is very complex and massive - can someone make an abstract, say how many of his pre-election plans are done? Some sort of "Trump's totals".

Comment: This is a very broad question. However, one website that evaluates whether presidents are fulfilling their promises is Politifact. It previously evaluated Obama's promises, and their page for Trump is [Trump-O-Meter](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/promises/trumpometer/)

Comment: This seems very broad, you're basically asking to summarize several years of promises and complex legislation, as well as how much abstract/vague promises are actually being implemented.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you are right. Will try to change it somehow

Comment: If you change it to focus on a single concrete promise("build wall and make Mexico pay", "repeal and replace Obamacare", etc.) and the legislation aimed at implementing it then it should be good. Otherwise, it might be closed or you'll just get broad "some things started, other things not started" answers.

Answer (score 6):

Using just the three things in your question Trump has done or progressed towards all of them. NAFTA is in the process of renegotiation, and Trump has withdrawn from the Paris Accord, TTIP/TPP, and Iran nuclear deal. He has also imposed widespread tariffs in order to correct trade imbalances that he views as disadvantageous deals. The border wall is a huge public works project that would take the better part of a decade or more to complete fully, but there was a small amount of funding allocated and prototypes proposed. Removing Obamacare requires the congress to actually pass a bill to remove it which they tried and failed, Trump has committed to not enforcing the individual mandate, which does eliminate some of the problems people had.

All candidates make a ton of promises while campaigning, and Trump may have made the most claims, some of which appear contradictory, there are still quite a few he has accomplished. Tax reform was a major promise that he was able to deliver on and so was removing the net neutrality regulations. He has also committed to expanding the military after a prolonged draw-down during the Obama years, specifically the Navy. Moving the embassy in Israel to Jerusalem, appointing a replacement for Scalia on the supreme court were both achieved. He has arguably achieved taking no salary as president if you count donating the salary. Immigration reform is something he has tried to achieve, and has done pretty much everything in his power, but congress needs to pass laws to really count this as completed. His initial foreign policy stance was more non interventionist to isolationist, this contrast with his hard stance against terrorism. He has continued drone strikes and covert operations against terrorist targets, and maintained a level of presence in the Syrian civil war, this seems to break and achieve a few different promises.

Trump has definitely progressed or achieved a lot of his promises, but since the spent years making several promises almost daily there are still tons of things that haven't happened or have even been broken. Its really hard to come up with any exact number or percentage, the [Trump-O-Meter](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/promises/trumpometer/) features several nearly identical claims which makes a long list even longer. Another way to look at his overall progress is that almost everything achieved so far has been via executive powers, as far as signing key legislation he really only has one success in tax reform. His accomplishments at this point are similar to Obama's at this point in his presidency.

Comment: Yes. Just what I want to see. Good answer and link to Trump-o-meter

Comment: Changed question a bit - according to comments. Can you change you answer a bit, to make it applicable to changed question?

Comment: @user2501323 - that is not how the Force... err.. Stack Exchange... works! It's explicitly against the rules to change questions in ways that invalidates existing well received answers